# plink takes connection host from putty's default connection

Tags: putty, plink

The only way the following command will work for me, is when putty's saved default connection does not define a host parameter.

```
 plink -l user -pw password myhost command
```

The result is:

```
myhost: Command not found.
```

Instead, what I need to type is:

```
plink -l user -pw password command
```

And the host is taken from putty's default connection.

Is the a way to work around this? I want both the default connection in putty, but I also want the ability to specify my own host for plink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem, and this works for me:

```
plink -load null host -l user -pw password
```

Where "null" is a non-existent session.